# If $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, then $|g(x)|\geq c |f(x)|^i$ for some $i<1$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f, g \in L^2[0,1]$. Further suppose that both $f(0)=g(0) = 0$. I want to show that if $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, then there exists constants $c, \epsilon > 0$ and $i<1$ such that $|g(x)|\geq c |f(x)|^i$ for all $x\in B_{\epsilon}(0)$. We cannot assume that $f,g$ are differentiable.

From the definition of the limit, we know that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x|<\delta$, then $\frac{|f(x)|}{|g(x)|} < \epsilon$. Hence, we know that for $|x|<\delta$, we have $\frac{1}{\epsilon}|f(x)| < |g(x)|$. However, this is not quite what I want. Unfortunately, $|f(x)|^i \geq |f(x)|$ for $i<1$ and for $x$ sufficiently small (if we impose continuity on $f$). Additionally, there does not exist any constant $c > 0$ such that
$c|f(x)|^i \leq |f(x)|$ as that would imply that $c \leq |f(x)|^{1-i}$, but if $f(x)$ is continuous and has a zero at $x=0$, then $|f(x)|^{1-i} < c$ for sufficiently small $x$.

The contrapositive direction seems reasonable, however, negating the second clause is giving me trouble.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x\log x$ ($g(0)=0$).

Comment: $g(x) \geq x^{.9} = f(x)^{.9}$ for sufficiently small $x$. I'm not sure if you were trying to present a counterexample, but what you posted falls in line of what I want to prove for arbitrary functions.

Comment: So your claim is that $-x\log x\ge x^{0.9}$ for sufficiently small $x>0$, i.e., $-x^{0.1}\log x\ge 1$ for sufficiently small $x>0$. But $-x^{0.1}\log x \to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$ by L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Any comments @Doofenshmert?

Comment: I agree with you. Plotting these functions on Mathematica lead me to my initial idea, but your comments convinced me that this does not hold.